# Can not connect to local database via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, database, database-connection

My local database connection was working fine few hours ago. but now I can not connect to local database via SSMS. I did not change any settings nor anything. I was working with my database from SSMS and then shutdown my laptop. Now I can connect to it.

```
Component name                            Version
------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio    12.0.2254.0
Microsoft SQL Server 2014
```

I can connect to other databases of different servers but can not access my local database. The error is showing ::

> ===================================
>
> Cannot connect to ---.
>
> ===================================
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
>
> ------------------------------ For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476
>
> ------------------------------ Error Number: 2 Severity: 20 State: 0
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo
>   ci, IServerType server)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
>
> ===================================
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `StartMenu` `Run` - type `services.msc` - look for service named `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)`. Right click on it and `start`.

Comment: thank you very much, the problem is solved. But can you explain what is the real problem and how did it solve the issue. It will be more helpful for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: I think what happened was when you re-started your `laptop`, the service didn't `start` automatically. (Because the setting may be `manual`) . This `service` is required to be started in order for your to work with `Sql Server`. You may want to change the `service` setting to start `automatically`, so that next time when you re-start your laptop, you do not have to go to the `services.msc` and start again.

Comment: But the problem occured only today, I never faced this problem before.

Comment: might have to check the `log` or `eventviewer` to be able to guess what exactly happened. See this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms189925.aspx), if you want to know more about database engine services.